# Angular 5 animation specific transitions

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

So my problem is I want to specify a specific animation between to pages.

I want to do one sort of animation when I click on a button which navigate to a specific URL(I am on page1 and navigate to page2) *http://localhost:4200/page2*. Then if I am on page1 and want to do goBack() I want a different animation when I return on the home page *http://localhost:4200*.

But with the :leave option of transition I can't achieve my goal, because I will have just one type of animation.
My idea is to do something like that:

```
trigger('zoomAndFade', [
  transition( 'page1=> page2', [
    query('.content', [
      style({fontSize: '1em', opacity: 1}),
      animate('2s ease-in-out', style({fontSize: '1.5em', opacity: 0}))
    ])
  ])

trigger('fade', [
  transition( 'page2=>page1', [
    query('.content', [
      style({opacity: 1}),
      animate('2s ease-in-out', style({opacity: 0}))
    ])
  ])
```

but how can I specify the state of a page to the animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Just add this getState methode to your app.component.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    getState(outlet) {
        return outlet.activatedRouteData.state;
    }
}
```

In your template, you need to get the new state of the router on a change event.

app.component.html

```
<main [@routerTransition]="getState(o)">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Now the animation in you component can distinguish between your pages.

Then you can have your transistions

```
trigger("routerTransition", [
    transition("* => settings", slideLeft),
    transition("settings => *", slideRight),
])
```

But your router needs to transmit data

```
{
    path: "settings",
    component: SettingsComponent,
    data: { state: "settings" }
}
```

And you animation can now feature :enter and :leave

```
query(":enter",
    [
        style({
            transform: "translateX(100%)"
        }),
        animate("0.4s ease-in-out",
            style({
                transform: "translateX(0%)"
            })
        )
    ], {
        optional: true
    }
),
query(":leave",
    [
        style({
            transform: "translateX(0%)"
        }),
        animate("0.4s ease-in-out",
            style({
                transform: "translateX(-100%)"
            })
        )
    ], {
        optional: true
    })
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "health",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this in the afternoon but when I do that I have this type of error : _synthetic property @routerTransition. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule"_

But I have imported the BrowserAnimationsModule in my app-module. So I don't understand why I have this error.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know this error. I was trying to achieve the same thing you wanted and this was the perfect way for me. Did you import the browser, BrowserAnimationsModule, AppRoutingModule and the RouterModule module in the app-module and also add it to the imports? you app.component needs  query, animate, style and everything you use as import as well

Comment: Yes I have all of that I will clean all my dependencies, and my cache. And I hope that will resolve my problem. 
Thank you very much !

Comment: Could you share me your package.json to compare versions please ?